# Alfresco disable google doc amp

Tags: installation, alfresco, google-docs, alfresco-module-package

i'm using alfresco 5.0.d

I noticed that google doc AMP was already installed.

I want to disable it. 
In the properties file   `tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco-global.properties` i have set the property `googledocs.enabled`   to false. But  I still see the google doc content create buttons.
How can i disable it ?

Answer (score 2):

If you would rather not have the Google docs functionality, then uninstalling it is also an option.
Please see http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/dev-extensions-tutorials-simple-module-uninstall-amp.html

Comment: Hi Ahmed. I can't do this cause i modified lot of file in share  webapp. SO i really want to disable the amp.

Comment: Did you see this? https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/end-user-discussions/alfresco-share/disable-google-integration-42-ce-10162012-0933  Does it help you at all?